# Copying and pasting charts works fine in break mode but skips charts and is erratic during normal runtime

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm copying multiple charts from separate sheets and pasting them all into one sheet. 
Everything works fine when I step through the code line by line in break mode. 
 When I run the macro, it skips charts and just acts erratic.
I've tried numerous methods for copy and pasting but it just doesn't seem to work.
 Any ideas what is wrong?
I'm pulling the names of charts to copy from a userform with a listbox.

This is the current code I'm trying to use to copy the charts:

```
For i = 0 To frmCustomChart.lstChartNames.ListCount - 1
    If frmCustomChart.lstChartNames.Selected(i) Then
        copyChartName = frmCustomChart.lstChartNames.List(i)
        Set copySheet = Sheets(copyChartName)
        For Each copychart In copySheet.ChartObjects
            copychart.Activate
            ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
            pasteSheet.Activate
            pasteSheet.Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol).Select
            pasteSheet.Paste
            pasteSheet.Range("A1").Select
            pasteCol = pasteCol + 11
        Next copychart
    End If
Next i
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Without getting to into it too deeply, it probably has to do with Selecting, and Activating your cells, ranges, sheets, or whatever.  If you can accomplish what you want by setting values instead of simulating selections, I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I just simplified your code and corrected the copying of chart line.

```
Dim copychart As ChartObject, i As Long, pasteRow As Long, pasteCol As Long
pasteRow = 1: pasteCol = 1 'Just initializing variable
With frmCustomChart.lstChartNames
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            Set copySheet = Sheets(.List(i))
            For Each copychart In copySheet.ChartObjects
                copychart.Chart.ChartArea.Copy 'I think this is the correct one
                pasteSheet.Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol).Activate
                pasteSheet.Paste
                pasteCol = pasteCol + 11
            Next copychart
        End If
    Next i
End With
```